# MySQL AS in WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database. I use a `SELECT AS` to measure "distance" between 2 points. What I want to do is use the same "distance" variable I created in the `SELECT` as a `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT first_name.last_name AS name WHERE name="John Doe"
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may want to consider putting your condition in a HAVING clause rather than in the WHERE clause.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html for details on the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 10):

Column aliases can only be referenced in the `ORDER BY` clause (as they do not exist yet in the `WHERE` part. You can do this (Although I do not necessarily recommend it as it may be slower.)

```
select name from
(select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as name from yourtable)
where name = 'John Doe'
```

Or you could do this:

```
select (firstname, ' ', lastname) as name from yourtable
where (firstname, ' ', lastname) = 'John Doe';
```

The only columns you have access to in the `WHERE` clause are the columns in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: ... because where clause is considered first and it can't see the alias as it is in the select part

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing 
put the condition on where clause

```
SELECT *,
    IF(check_out='0000-00-00 00:00:00', NOW(), check_out) AS occ_test
FROM occupied_room1
WHERE
DATE(IF(check_out='0000-00-00 00:00:00', NOW(), check_out)) = ' 2017-07-02';
```