# Possible to check WHERE on an AS statement variable? MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Would someone explain why I can't seem to use a WHERE clause on my AS variable (not sure what those are actually called.

if i do something like `WHERE a.n = gameone` in the same exact place it works.

Can i not use a WHERE clause on a var thats created like `AVG(b.r) AS fra` ?

If i can. how can i?

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.n, a.t, a.d,
  AVG(b.r) AS fra, COUNT(b.id) as tvotes
FROM `games` a
LEFT JOIN `games_ratings` b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE fra >= 2
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.ts
DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: is that something you have to use instead of WHERE specifically for vars created with an AS clause?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611451/mysql-as-in-where-statement

Comment: Well. You have to use `HAVING` when you need to filter data by aggregate functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the values being selected are not in scope for `WHERE` because which rows are selected depends on the `WHERE`. If you really want to do a condition on them, use `HAVING` but note that `HAVING` clauses are not optimized.

See [the MySQL documentation on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) for more information on `HAVING`.

Comment: Is that really my best bet? The idea is to sort by the ratings of my games. so its pretty much the only way i can get the int.

Comment: alright just tried out HAVING. never head of it before, but it does the trick. thanks! I cant mark this an answer for another 6 minutes it says. so ill mark it when it will let me. thanks again.

Comment: Is the performance of using `HAVING` actually a problem (in the spirit of avoiding premature optimizations)? If so you could also denormalize (i.e. store the average rating explicitly in addition to the individual ratings). Another thing to do might be to use a subquery to filter out games with no ratings of at least `2` (and therefore an average below `2`), but that might actually be slower.