# How get max from two field of one record

Tags: mysql, max

I want give max from two field of one record in table ( of mysql).
my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `testtbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
)
```

and for example my data is :

> 1 , '2012-12-04' , '2013-02-02'

but when I use below sql , I face with error.
sql code is :

```
select max(startdate,enddate) from `testtbl`
```

Comment: If your problem has been solved using anyone's asnwer, then please dont forget to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function is used to grab the maximum value of a field of all rows, you are looking for the [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function:

```
select GREATEST(startdate,enddate) from `testtbl`
```

Comment: For that you can use the [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function :)

Comment: when use GREATEST function , i can not use result in where , for example `select GREATEST(startdate,enddate) as d from testtbl where d> 2012-02-02` , d unknown.

Comment: Try using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, for more info check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611451/mysql-as-in-where-statement

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you'd be better off using an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)-construct, because you have the data in separate fields. Maybe something like this:

```
select if(startdate>enddate,startdate,enddate) 
from `testtbl`;
```

An alternative would be using [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

You're better off using [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) when you have all the data in different rows in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select case when startdate > enddate then startdate 
            else enddate end as GreaterDate 
from 'testtb1'
```